# Apache Superset - Concurrent loading of dashboard slices (Athena)

Tags: gunicorn, gevent, amazon-athena, apache-superset

I've got a dashboard with a few slices setup. Slices are loading one after the other, not concurrently. This results in a bad user experience. My data is sitting on S3 and I'm using the Athena connector for queries. I can see that the calls to Athena are fired in order, with each query waiting for the one before it to finish before running.

I'm using gevent, which is far as I can tell shouldn't be a problem?

Below is an extract from my Superset config:

```
SUPERSET_WORKERS = 8
WEBSERVER_THREADS = 8
```

It used to be set to 2 and 1 respectively, but I upped it to 8 each see if that could be the issue. I'm getting the same result though.

Is this a simple misconfiguration issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand multiProcessing and multiThreading before increasing the workers and threads for `gunicorn`. If you are looking at `CPU intense operations`, you want many processes' while you probably want many threads for `I/O intensive` operations.

With your problem, you don't need many process; but threads within a process. With that config, next step would be to debug how you're spawning greenlets. (gevents facilitates `concurrency`. Concurrency !== Parallel Processing).

To bootstrap `gunicorn` with multiple threads you could do something like this:

`gunicorn -b localhost:8000 main:app --threads 30 --reload`

Please post more code to facilitate targeted help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured it out a week or so ago. The issue was that the application handles multi processing just fine. The connection between the Python app and JDBC jar is the problem. Each Athena query starts a new JVM. So instead of multi threading calls on the JVM, it waits, kills the running JVM, and starts a new one.

Comment: @VinayRanjan I couldn't solve it on a code or configuration level. I didn't want to edit any of the existing code, but I'm sure there's a way to tweak it to get it working. What I ended up doing is running the app in docker containers, and just using multiple containers with a load balancer. The load balancer will then distribute the multiple requests over the multiple containers, each container handling a call to Athena basically. Throwing resources at the problem is not the best solution, but it was the fastest.